# Material UI tooltip doesn't display on custom component, despite spreading props to that component

Tags: reactjs, tooltip, material-ui

I am having difficulties making the Material UI tooltip actually appear when hovering over a component. As far as I can tell, I am doing about the simplest implementation of the tooltip component: I import it directly (no custom styles or anything else yet), and I wrap it around another component that spreads out its props at the top level.

From reading the documentation it should be that simple, but it is not appearing on hover, and in the React DevTools I see that the anchorEl prop of  is undefined.

```
import Tooltip from '@material-ui/core/Tooltip';

const containerComponent = () => (
    <Tooltip text="Planner"><PlannerIcon /></Tooltip>
)
```

PlannerIcon.js

```
const PlannerIcon = (props) => (
  <Icon xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 18 18"
    {...props}
  >
    <path d="M14.71,3.11V14.88H2.94V3.11H14.71m1-1H1.94V15.88H15.71V2.11Z"/>
    <line x1="1.94" y1="9" x2="15.71" y2="9" strokeMiterlimit="10"/>
    <line x1="8.83" y1="2.12" x2="8.83" y2="15.77" strokeMiterlimit="10"/>
  </Icon>
  );
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

**Your Tooltip is not working properly because the child of  a Material-UI Tooltip must be able to hold a ref.**

The following can hold a ref:

- *Any Material-UI component*
- *class components i.e. React.Component or React.PureComponent*
- *DOM (or host) components e.g. div or button*
- *React.forwardRef components*
- *React.lazy components*
- *React.memo components*

PlannerIcon is not any of the above, **it's a function component**.
I'll suggest Two solutions for the problem:

1. **Surround *PlannerIcon* with div as a parent element (div can hold a ref):**

   ```
   <Tooltip text="Planner">
     <div>
      <PlannerIcon />
     </div>
   </Tooltip>
   ```
2. **Convert *PlannerIcon* into a class component:**

   ```
   class PlannerIcon extends React.Component {
     render(){
       return(
        <Icon xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 18 18"
         {...props}
        >
          <path d="M14.71,3.11V14.88H2.94V3.11H14.71m1-1H1.94V15.88H15.71V2.11Z"/>
          <line x1="1.94" y1="9" x2="15.71" y2="9" strokeMiterlimit="10"/>
          <line x1="8.83" y1="2.12" x2="8.83" y2="15.77" strokeMiterlimit="10"/>
        </Icon>
       )
     }
   };
   ```

Comment: This was the issue, it's working now with adding the div! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, @Ido. Your solution provided worked for me.

Comment: Nice. In my case I used `<span></span>`

Answer (score 10):

There is no need for the div workaround or turning your functional component into a class one. You can use forwardRef instead and it will work too:

```
const PlannerIcon = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <Icon xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 18 18"
    {...props}
    ref={ref}
  >
    <path d="M14.71,3.11V14.88H2.94V3.11H14.71m1-1H1.94V15.88H15.71V2.11Z"/>
    <line x1="1.94" y1="9" x2="15.71" y2="9" strokeMiterlimit="10"/>
    <line x1="8.83" y1="2.12" x2="8.83" y2="15.77" strokeMiterlimit="10"/>
  </Icon>
  ));
```

I'm not sure what the `Icon` component is about, you might need to turn it into an `<svg>` tag.

If anyone is using typescript, the syntax is a little confusing, the first type is the one for the `ref` and second for the `props` (don't ask me why):

```
const PlannerIcon = React.forwardRef<SVGSVGElement | null, IPlannerIconProps>((props, ref) => {
    ...
});
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in 2020, 2021, ...

Answer (score 0):

I know this might be weird to ask but perhaps try to import svg icon as component, since react 16.4(not sure right now) you can import svgs as components.

```
import { ReactComponent as YourName} from './assets/yourfile.svg';
```

then you could simply do this:

```
const PlannerIcon = (props) => (
  <YourName {...props}/>
  );
```

let me know if you tried and if it helped.

@edit
I do not see in their documentation any prop called text, perhaps you mean title?
[Tooltip api](https://material-ui.com/api/tooltip/)

Comment: I'm applying a lot of styled-components overrides to all my SVGs, which is why I'm targeting things the way I am. I did change the prop from text to title (I was using text originally because my end goal is to create a separate ToolTip component that imports the Material one and then adds styled-components overrides, but I'm trying to keep it simple for now). However, even after changing the prop to "title", it isn't popping up.

Comment: I also just tried this using a non-SVG as the anchor element, but it still didn't work.

Comment: this is indeed weird behaviour @ipenguin67 . What happends if you use their standard tooltip example?  https://codesandbox.io/s/wxgo4

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way I found to create an SVG icon that is Tooltip friendly:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import SvgIcon from '@mui/material/SvgIcon';
import {ReactComponent as PlannerSvg} from './planner.svg';

// Allows functional component to use ref - and thus be allowed inside a tooltip
const PlannerIcon = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <SvgIcon {...props}>
      <PlannerSvg />
    </SvgIcon>
  );
});
export default PlannerIcon
```

I like this implementation because:

- still functional
- The .svg itself can be updated without changing code
- Short and sweet.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you need title="Planner" not text="Planner".

`<Tooltip title="Planner"><PlannerIcon /></Tooltip>`

Comment: My mistake -- I just switched it to the correct prop of "title" but it still doesn't appear to show up.