# MUI: The `children` component of the Tooltip is not forwarding its props correctly

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm having issues with MUI tooltip and refs - whole message goes as follows:

> MUI: The `children` component of the Tooltip is not forwarding its props correctly.
> Please make sure that props are spread on the same element that the ref is applied to.

What I have - basically, I've recreated more or less bootstrap-style button (with help from MUI docs). The problem is that I've tried to preserve previously used `Button` from `react-bootstrap`, both APIs are different when it comes to `variant` param. Then I've wrapped Button component with MUI Tooltip component and at the end, wrapped Tooltip with `CopyToClipboard` component from `react-copy-to-clipboard`. I've read the error message but it didn't help me - it didn't change anything except that previous error message was replaced with new one

> Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `outlined`

No idea why though, as there's no such param for MUI `Button` component.
From what I've read, `props` not only contain params, but also Event Listeners (I've checked that with `Object.keys(props)` and `Object.values(props)` and there are some event listeners indeed). So, I've tried both things here:

1. deleting `variant` key from props after assinging its value to some local value - no luck, as props seems to be read-only
2. destructuring props and getting event listeners, then passing them to `MUIButton` - nothing changed.

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-borg-s6ye3y?file=/src/App.jsx)

Its worth mentioning that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57528471/2259080) workaround with surrounding `Button` with `div` does work indeed, but its more like a workaround rather than real solution. My question is: can I keep "my" API intact, given that one parameter that is present in both components expects `variant` to be something completely different? And second question is - what's the real solution here, what am I missing? Am I composing my props for `MUIButton` wrong, missing something that is not an Event Listener, but still required?